# approval process action 1

Tags: approval-process

If we create a customer name and checkbox true then it must assign to two users to get approval ( any two user) but after first user approved then it automatically send to second user for approval how ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create two approval processes.

After first one is approved, you can submit for 2nd approval through process builder.